# how to apply patch from Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory?

Tags: security, patch, oracle-database

I installed Oracle database but no longer need it. I've tried uninstalling it but that still leaves a lot of security vulnerabilities on my machine. So now I'm looking to apply the [Oracle Critical Patch Update Advisory](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpujul2021.html) I've been clicking around but cannot find any download that might allow me to update the faulty components.

How can these updates be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update products listed in the Update Advisory.
If Oracle is now uninstalled, it's unlikely that you can find any for the
left-overs.

I suggest installing Oracle again, then uninstalling it using an uninstalled
like
[Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/products/revo-uninstaller-free/),
which will take care of the left-overs.

Answer (score 0):

An Oracle license is needed to install updates.